# How to edit this table responsive script?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using this script to automatically adapt tables to Smartphone view.
It works perfectly! But in some pages, I will have more than one table, and the script seems working only with the first table.
Look at my example, resize your browser window: http://elenatest.altervista.org/index.html

Here's JS code put in the body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var headertext = [],

            headers = document.querySelectorAll("#MyTable th"),
            tablerows = document.querySelectorAll("#MyTable th"),
            tablebody = document.querySelector("#MyTable tbody");

            for(var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
                var current = headers[i];

                headertext.push(current.textContent.replace(/\r?\n|\r/,""));

            } 

            for (var i = 0, row; row = tablebody.rows[i]; i++) {
                for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
                    col.setAttribute("data-th", headertext[j]);
                } 
            }
</script>
```

Is there a way to make this script running for all the tables in the page?

EDIT

I changed the ID with a CLASS. Here's JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var headertext = [],

            headers = document.querySelectorAll(".MyTable th"),
            tablerows = document.querySelectorAll(".MyTable th"),
            tablebody = document.querySelector(".MyTable tbody");

            for(var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
                var current = headers[i];

                headertext.push(current.textContent.replace(/\r?\n|\r/,""));

            } 

            for (var i = 0, row; row = tablebody.rows[i]; i++) {
                for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
                    col.setAttribute("data-th", headertext[j]);
                } 
            }
        </script>
```

And obviously in my HTML:

```
<table class="MyTable">
 <!--etc etc-->
</table>
```

Comment: id's are supposed to be unique and should occur only once per HTML page. You should use a class instead if you want to apply some CSS / select HTML elements in JavaScript for multiple elements. You should use https://validator.w3.org to validate your HTML, it will warn you about mistakes like that. :)

Comment: You're right! :) thanks! I changed the id with class in the HTML/CSS and in the JS.  `#MyTable` becomes `.MyTable`. But, with the code I put above it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By selecting "table" first, then apply your function on each:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("table")).forEach(function (table) {
  var headertext = [];
  var headers    = table.querySelectorAll("th");
  var tablebody  = table.querySelector("tbody");
  var i, j, row, col;

  for(var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    headertext.push(headers[i].textContent.replace(/\r?\n|\r/,""));
  }

  for (i = 0; row = tablebody.rows[i]; i++) {
    for (j = 0; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
      col.setAttribute("data-th", headertext[j]);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe it's not everything clear for me. I'm sorry but I'm not very good with JS. I copied your code but it still doesn't work. Do I have to change something about your code?

Comment: @Maki Fixed. I forgot to cast NodeList as Array.

Comment: Wonderful!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As you are using an id `#MyTable` you assume that you'll have only one table on your page.

First, you should change this to class to be semantically more correct.
Then, you need to iterate on tablebody as you do with headers.

```
for(var i = 0; i < tablebody.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand. :) I'm not very good with JS. I'm trying to learn. I changed the id with a class.. Then I have to change the code for  `tablebody `? Only in the line you pasted? Thanks